# Generate data for secionlists in react native

Tags: react-native-flatlist

The `SectionList` in react native requires the data feed like the following:

```
sections={[
                {title: 'D', data: ['Devin']},
                {title: 'J', data: ['Jackson', 'James', 'Jillian', 'Jimmy', 'Joel', 'John', 'Julie']},
              ]}
```

My understanding of data above is a object of object array. I can generate an object array like this:

```
let obj_arr = [];
obj1 = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
       };
obj_arr.push(obj1);
obj2 = {
        c: 3,
        b: 4
       };
obj_arr.push(obj2);
```

How to generate object for object array of `obj_arr`?

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse() method?

Comment: The data required may just be an object array. I am testing now.